# Vertx with Spring Oauth2

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2, vert.x

We have many microservices running using spring boot and we have secured them using Spring oauth2 (AuthorizationServer and Resource server microservices). However for one of the microservices which are using vertx as its throughput is much more than spring reactive web.I now need vertx end points to be secured using oauth2(configuring it as resource server), but it doesn't work since vertx starts its own server. So I configured OAuth2AuthHandler of vertx with authorization path and token path with little luck. I appreciate if someone can give insights on wiring spring oauth2 with vertx.

Comment: I know this is not what you want but what didn't work for you with: `OAuth2AuthHandler`? I'm working on improving its usability so it would be nice to hear your feedback.